# Como modificar um System.out.println já existente

Tags: java

Caso eu execute esse código

```
public class main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        teste(20);
    }

    public static void teste(int maximo)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < maximo; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i + " de " + maximo);    
        }
    }
}
```

el vai imprimir isso

```
0 de 30
1 de 30
2 de 30
3 de 30
4 de 30
5 de 30
6 de 30
7 de 30
8 de 30
9 de 30
10 de 30
11 de 30
12 de 30
13 de 30
14 de 30
15 de 30
16 de 30
17 de 30
18 de 30
19 de 30
20 de 30
```

porem eu gostaria que em vez da linha se repetir 20 vezes apenas modifique a primeira.

Se puderem me indicar uma API que consiga executar isso também ajudaria.

Comment: Ficou confusa sua pergunta. Você quer que apenas a mensagem da primeira linha seja diferente, e as demais se mantenham 'x de N', é isso? Se não for, explique melhor, por favor.

Comment: Se eu entendi bem você quer limpar a tela, ou mostrar apenas o ultimo resultado?

Answer (score 5):

Use `System.out.print()` e o  caractere de escape `\r` no final do texto:

```
public static void teste(int maximo)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < maximo; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(i + " de " + maximo + "\r");    
    }
}
```

Ao invés de `System.out.println()`, que faz mudança de linha após o *display*, `System.out.print()` imprime sempre na mesma linha.
O caractere de escape `\r` faz com que o cursor volte para o inicio da linha.

O caracter de escape é ignorado pela *console* do *Eclipse*, terá por isso de executar o programa numa *janela de comando* do Windows.

Da forma como o código está não se conseguirá ver nada, já que a janela será aberta e fechada quase de imediato.
Para testar introduza as seguintes alterações:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        teste(4);
    }
    public static void teste(int maximo)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < maximo; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i + " de " + maximo + "\r");    
            try {
                //Espera meio segundo antes de prosseguir
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\r\n");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Espera que uma tecla seja premida antes de sair do programa
        String tecla = keyboard.next();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Continua imprimindo o mesmo resultado.

Comment: eclipse tinha um bug antigo, o console não suporta \r https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936, parece que foi resolvido nos ultimos releases, ou em um release candidate. De qualquer forma se você executar a aplicação java via commandline o \r vai funcionar normalmente

Comment: @ReginaldoSoares Ia agora perguntar ao AP onde ele estava a executar o código, se no IDE ou via *command line*.

Comment: Estou executando no Console do ECLIPSE

Comment: Tal como o @ReginaldoSoares disse na *console* do *Eclipse* não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Se o intuito é mostrar apenas o útimo resultado, então você pode setar uma variável e executar o `System.out.print` no final:

```
private string resultadoFinal:

...

public static void teste(int maximo)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < maximo; i++)
    {
           resultadoFinal = i + " de " + maximo;
    }
}

System.out.print(resultadoFinal);
```

No entanto se a execução não for dentro de um loop e este código é ilustrativo apenas e ainda supondo que os resultado enviado ou *output* serão assíncronos, então é como o @Ramaral disse, no Eclipse não irá funcionar usar o `\r`

Comment: Eu quero fazer essa mudança apenas por estética, eu executei no CMD com "\r" e não funcionou do mesmo jeito.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Funciona sim. Verifique se está a usar `System.out.print()` e não `System.out.println()`.